# Cloning git repository from http URL with tortoisehg

Tags: git, clone, tortoisehg, hg-git

I have TortoiseHg with the hg-git extension installed. I know it is working as I can clone repositories from github using `hg clone git://github.com/foo/bar.git`

However, I am trying to clone a repository located at http://www-dev.cockos.com/wdl/WDL.git/
If I do `hg clone http://www-dev.cockos.com/wdl/WDL.git/` it unsurprisingly reports:

```
abort: 'http://www-dev.cockos.com/wdl/WDL.git/' does not appear to be an hg repository!
```

I then tried putting the git:// prefix on, which looked like it was doing something (says "Importing Hg objects into Git", but eventually times out with the message:

```
destination directory: WDL.git
importing Hg objects into Git
abort: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected  
host has failed to respond
```

Is there any flag I can use to tell hg-git to do the clone using the http URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading the [release notes](http://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/docs/) of **[dulwich](http://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/)** (the Python library for Git interactions, used by [Hg-Git](http://hg-git.github.com/)), it is not clear that http protocol is supported for Git repo.

Actually, [bug 373688](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dulwich/+bug/373688) and [this thread](https://bitbucket.org/abderrahim/hg-git/issue/18/cannot-clone-git-repo-over-http) seem to indicate that http://.../repo.git isn't an url currently supported by dulwich (and, by extension, by hg-git).
Only `file:///`, `git://` or `git+ssh://` are available at the moment.

Comment: Thanks. So am I forced to install git or are there any workarounds?

Comment: @Mark: Hg-Git don't need any git binary installed locally. Adding Git won't solve the fact that http protocol isn't supported by Hg-Git.

Comment: what I mean is, if I want to look at the source code in that repository, my only option is to use actual git?

Comment: @Mark: yes, if you want to clone the git repo, you need msysgit (you don't have necessary to "install" it: there is a portable version at http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list that you can simply un-compress anywhere you want)

Answer (score 0):

Problem should be fixed now since Dulwich 0.8.1 now understands http protocol.